# Как изменить цвет svg картинки отрисованной на canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

Есть canvas на котором отрисовано (drawImage) изображение в формате svg. Требуется поменять цвет. Первое, что приходит в голову это перебрать все пиксели и поменять их на нужные. Но как это сделать? Ведь изображение может быть не правильной формы, например лист или облако. Да и ресурсов много нужно наверно. Может есть решения более красивые. Подскажите

Comment: Изменить цвет svg, а потом уже рисовать?